# "ValidationError: Post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required" in Vue.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I have two directories where vue, node exist. And I have the vue build file in the node folder.

I am currently processing requests from nodes in the vue. However, the event occurs but the data does not cross.

I have the following code, I sent form data via create, but the return data is empty. Also, in mongodb, title and content are require: true, so I get an error like the title.

Please help me.

**node/routes/api**

```
...
const Post = require('../db/post');

router.post('/new', (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content
  });

  post.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.json({ result: 0 });
      return;
    }
    res.json({ result: 1 });
  });
});
...
```

**vue/src/component/new**

```
<template>
  <div id="form-group">
    name : <input v-model="post.title">
    content : <input v-model="post.content">
    <button v-on:click="new" >New</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      post: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    new: function (evt) {
      this.$http.post('/api/post/new', {
        post: this.post
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.result === 0) {
          alert('Error')
        }
        if (response.data.result === 1) {
          alert('Success')
          this.$router.push('/')
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert('error')
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check in your browser's network console that your `api/post/new` call has the right parameters included.

Comment: When a create event occurs, I just return {result: 0}.

Comment: The request url, method, and status code (200) are all normal.

Comment: My mongodb's title and content are require: true. If I change this to optional: true, the text is created normally. Of course, this is saved, but the title and contents are returned with an empty string.